# Analyze in Excel report not working for end user

Tags: excel, powerbi

I have created reports using the Analyze in Excel feature. I have saved these reports into a shared location for the user to access. The user has access to the workspace as a viewer and has a pro license. But when he opens the excel file from the shared location, he is getting the Forbidden Activity ID error and cant refresh the data.

I thought if I create the reports using analyze in excel then the user with a pro license will be able to view and refresh the excel report regardless of where it is saved?

Can you please advise further? Is there something I am missing?

Thanks

Yasir

Comment: For a viewer role they will need Build Permission on the dataset

Comment: how do i grant them this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Analyze in Excel option for those users set as the role 'Viewer' (Those set as Members or Contributors will have this access by default), by enabling the 'Build' permission.

In the Power BI Service, go to the workspace datasets and click on the '...' for more options:
[image: Dataset More Settings]

Select the 'Manage Permissions' option

[image: Dataset Full Options]

This will give a list of the user and their permissions. Select the '...' for the user options and select the 'Add Build' Permission.

[image: Power BI Add Build Permission]

The user in the 'Viewer' role can now access the data set via Analyse in Excel

Comment: Thanks for that Jon! I will confirm with the user once he is back from annual leave